# Array doesnt fill/map() right React

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, leaflet

I'm trying to map an array but I think it filled wrong because it gives `undefined` for the things I added a few things but they come up as `undefined` for some reasons

[image]

if you look at the top its sort of an separate array in the top and the rest will be `undefined` if I try to get them with `.map()`

this picture is from a console log here:

```
           {RuuviTag.map((tag) => (



              <div key={tag.MAC}>
                {console.log(tag.MAC),
                console.log(tag)


                }

                <Marker position={[tag.Latitude.replace(/,/g, '.'), tag.Longitude.replace(/,/g, '.')]} icon={new Icon({
                   iconUrl: tag.colorIcon,
                    iconSize: [25, 41],
                     iconAnchor: [12, 41] })} >
                  <Popup>
                    <h1>{tag.MAC}
                       </h1>
                       <h1>
                       </h1>
                  </Popup>
                </Marker>





              </div>
            ))}\
```

this is the code where I fill the array:

```
 async function getData() {
    setLoading(true);

    ref.onSnapshot((querySnapshot) => {
      let items = [];

      querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
       
        let item = doc.data()
        console.log(doc.data().RawData)
        PostRawData(doc.data().RawData).then(function (result) {
          console.log(result)
          item.decryptedData = result.data;
        });

        checkBoundaries(doc.data().RawData).then(function (result) {
          console.log(result)
          item.colorIcon = result;
        });
        console.log(item)

        items.push(item);
        console.log(items)

      });
```

but when I try to map the colorIcon or something from the decrypted data it comeds up as `undefined`

Does anyone know how to fix this? I couldn't find this issue anywhere

Comment: You're using promise syntax `.then`, but you're treating it like it's synchronous. You need to `await` those things instead if you want to treat it like synchronous code. Have a look into how asynchronous code gets treated in the event loop, and promises vs async/await

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should push item after done async functions.

Like this

```
let item = doc.data()
Promise.all([
  PostRawData(doc.data().RawData),
  checkBoundaries(doc.data().RawData),
]).then(function (result) {
  item.decryptedData = result[0].data;
  item.colorIcon = result[1]
  items.push(item)
})
```

Comment: Oh, I will updated without arrow function expression.